# qupzilla compile error in yocto krogoth version

Tags: cross-browser, yocto, qt5.6

When I compile qupzilla 2.0 supports qt5.6 base its giving below error.

> Project MESSAGE: Using following defines: | Project MESSAGE:
>   QUPZILLA_SHAREDLIBRARY QUPZILLA_VERSION=\"2.0.2\"
>   QT_NO_URL_CAST_FROM_STRING QT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER
>   USE_LIBPATH=\"/usr/lib\" USE_DATADIR=\"/usr/share/qupzilla\"
>   GIT_REVISION=\"635d392e66\" QZ_WS_X11 |
>   Project ERROR: Unknown
>   module(s) in QT: x11extras |
>
> ERROR: Error calling  /home//build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/qt5/qmake
>   -makefile -o Makefile  -r   /home/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/qupzilla/5.6.3+gitAUTOINC+6e445dcc05-r0/git/QupZilla.pro

below is my recipe

```
DESCRIPTION = "falkon browser https://github.com/Cockatrice/Cockatrice/issues/205"
LICENSE = "GPL-3.0"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYRIGHT;md5=1d4ea452ed7ae778545f2dda5963c9fd"
require recipes-qt/qt5/qt5-git.inc
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/QupZilla/qupzilla.git;branch=v2.0"
SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"
S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
DEPENDS = " qtbase qtwebengine qtx11extras qtdeclarative"
inherit qmake5
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "installed-vs-shipped"
```

Is anything is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ensure that you have x11 in DISTRO_FEATURES and you may also want to add

```
require recipes-qt/qt5/qt5.inc
```